# Prevent backspace from deleting in Jquery

Tags: jquery, keypress, keycode, backspace

I have a text box. When a user presses the backspace button, I want to prevent the backspace from deleting text and to give a specific alert e.g. "Do you want to delete"? along with two buttons. Only when the user confirms the delete operation, the subsequent backspace button clicks would delete the texts.

I have written the below code. Though it works fine. but it is not able to prevent the backspace from deleting the text. Can anyone help me out in this?

```js
$("#txtCustNameSHP").keyup(function (e) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if (keypresscount == 0 && key == 8 || key == 46) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.uxMsg({
            title: "Confirmation",
            msg: "Do you want to delete the Shipper?",
            button1Text: "YES",
            button2Text: "NO",
            button1Click: function () {
                // CUSTOMER LOV
                //$("#" + txtCustCodeSHP).text("");                        
                keypresscount++;
            },
            button2Click: function () {
                return false;
            },
            width: "350px",
            height: "100px"
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtCustNameSHP" value="foobar" />
```

Comment: That sounds....truly awful. Are you aware of just how badly that's going to trip people up, particularly touch-typists?

Comment: Instead, you can use onblur event to check if the value is removed and alert the user for same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**issue 1:** you should use `keydown` instead of `keyup` because keyup will be triggered after deletion already done

**issue 2:** your event is `e` not `event`

```js
$("#txtCustNameSHP").keydown(function (e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  if (key == 8 || key == 46) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtCustNameSHP" value="foobar" />
```

---

#### With a Confirmation message:

```js
$("#txtCustNameSHP").keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    if (key == 8 || key == 46) {
        if (typeof(dontDelete) == "undefined") {
            var r = confirm("You're about to delete!\nAre you sure?");
            if (r == true) {
                dontDelete = false;
            } else {
                dontDelete = true;
            }
        }
        if (dontDelete) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtCustNameSHP" value="foobar" />
<button type="button" onclick="dontDelete = false">enable delete</button>
<button type="button" onclick="dontDelete = true">disable delete</button>
<button type="button" onclick="dontDelete = undefined">Reset (ask on delete)</button>
```

**options:**

- `dontDelete = undefined;` user will be presented with a *confirmation*
  and choice will be *rememberd*
- `dontDelete = false;` user will be able to delete.
- `dontDelete = true;` user will *NOT* be able to delete.

Comment: How to prevent keypress event from triggering multiple times

Comment: you can add a condition but what's the expected behavior? when do you want it to stop triggering? and when do you want it to trigger again?

Comment: ok, added a confirmation message option, let me know it's not what you're looking for

Comment: Ya thank you . it worked.. this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 5):

First Thing- bind a callback handler to the event *keydown*, not *keyup*, because you want to catch the button when its clicked instead of after that. Then use `e.which` to check which key was pressed.  From [the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) :

> To determine which key was pressed, examine the event object that is
>   passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing
>   properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which
>   property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the key code.

https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

```
$("#txtCustNameSHP").keydown( function(e){  
  if( e.which == 8){   
    e.preventDefault();  
    return false;   
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#input').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 8) {
    var conf = confirm('Do you want to delete the Shipper?')
    if(!conf) e.preventDefault();
    else $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" value="foobar" />
```